Computing a definite integral knowing its equation
Here the problem: Let f(x) continuous on [-1,1] such that $$f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2} + x^2f(x^2) (*)$$ Calculate $$ \int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx $$
EDIT: Actually, I found this problem from a calculus 1 textbook when I just started to learn about definite integration; therefore, I simply didn't think this problem would be too complex for a starter like me. However, it is solvable but may be my current knowledge couldn't make this problem fully answered (though the answer from that textbook is ${3\pi}\over 4$)

Here are all my attempts that I could initially think of: (you can skip this part and take a look at EDIT part if you don't want to see these boring and lenthy processes)


1. The first instinct when I see this is to take the integral from -1 to 1 of both sides of (*):$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx = \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx+\int_{-1}^1x^2f(x^2)dx$$ $$\iff (Let \int_{-1}^1f(x)dx = A) A = \frac{\pi}{2} +\int_{-1}^1x^2f(x^2)dx $$


Seeing $x^2f(x^2)$ is an even function, so $\int_{-1}^1 x^2f(x^2)dx =2 \int_{0}^1x^2f(x^2)dx = \int_{0}^1xf(x^2)d(x^2) = \int_{0}^1\sqrt{t}f(t)dt$


Which leads me to do something with (*) to have $\sqrt{t}f(t)$:
$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+xf(x^2)$$ And then substitute $x = \sqrt{x}$ I have: $\frac{f(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{{1-x}\over{x}}+\sqrt{x}f(x)(**)$ (as I do substiution on [0,1] for next integration so I might gather into one square root sign)


Take integration from 0 to 1 of both sides of (**) I then end up getting back my initial transformation of (*)


2. My second attempt is that (since both sides of (*) are all even function)
$$\int_{0}^1f(x)d(x^2)=\int_{0}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}d(x^2) +\int_{0}^1x^2f(x^2)d(x^2)$$ $$\iff \int_{0}^12xf(x)dx={2\over 3}+\int_{0}^1xf(x)dx$$ $$\iff \int_{0}^1xf(x)dx={2\over3}$$


Here I guess it would be one clue but still have no idea linking to the problem


3. I try integrating by parts but then it seems more complicated


4. After 3 times trying  but  failing, I tried to see whether it is solvable or not, what I thought is that:


Start with what we easily have $$2\int_{0}^1f(x)dx= {\pi\over2}+\int_{0}^1\sqrt{x}f(x)dx(1)$$


And
$$\int_{0}^1xf(x)dx = 2/3$$


Let $$\int_{0}^1\sqrt{x}f(x)dx=k$$ We have:$$\int_{0}^1(2\sqrt{x}f(x)-xf(x))dx =\int_{0}^1(2-\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x}f(x)dx=2k-{2\over3}$$


Also from (1) we have:  $$\int_{0}^12(2-\sqrt{x})f(x)dx = \pi$$


$$\Rightarrow\int_{0}^1(2-\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^12(2-\sqrt{x})f(x)dx = \int_{0}^1(4-x)f(x)dx = \pi + 2k - {2\over3}$$
which is, however, the same as (1)


From here, because the result is always looping back to the hypothesis, I think it is unsolvable due to the lack of details of the problem for a starter to solve, however, I also find it is unreasonable as those points are just proving the fixation of the value of k

EDIT: After a very long time learning from people's reference, I guess it can be solved in this way:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2} + x^2f(x^2)$$$$f(x^2)=\sqrt{1-x^4} + x^4f(x^4)$$$$f(x^4)=\sqrt{1-x^8} + x^8f(x^8)$$
$$...$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x) =\sqrt{1-x^2} + x^2\sqrt{1-x^4}+x^6\sqrt{1-x^8}+...=\sqrt{1-x^2} + \frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{2^n}\sqrt{1-x^{2^n}}=\sqrt{1-x^2} +\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{2^n-2}\sqrt{1-x^{2^n}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_{-1}^1f(x)dx = {\pi \over 2} + \int_{-1}^1\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{2^n-2}\sqrt{1-x^{2^n}}$$
This is an absolutely different solution to this problem and perhaps it equals ${3\pi \over 4}$, in the hope of proving $\int_{-1}^1\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{2^n-2}\sqrt{1-x^{2^n}} = {\pi \over 4}$
Nevertheless, computing this currently exceeds my knowledge and ability, so please help me compute this to put an end to this problem

Did you try a change of variable?

Did you try integration by parts?

@jjagmath of course, if I integrate by parts then it would show up derivative of f(x) or f(x^2), but the equation is much more complicated. I substitute t = x^2 then the part x^2*f(x^2) would be sqrt(x)f(x) and cant transform it into the f(x) to make it more simple

In this forum you're expected to show your efforts. Don't post them in a comment, edit your question to include them.

@jjagmath you're right, I have updated my lengthy attempt but still getting stuck. Do you have any suggestions?

Hint:  try the substitution $u=\sin^{-1}(x)$

@F.Wright I dont think it would work, or where or when should I substitute?

Let $g(x) = x^2f(x)$, then $g(x) - g(x^2) = x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}$. This leads to $f(x) = \frac1{x^2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{2^n} \sqrt{1-x^{2^n}}$ for $0 < |x| < 1$. Integrate this term by term allow you to express the integral as a sum...

Thank you but may be I'm not so deep on this so I don't understand how this was done

Notice $g(x) = g(x^{2^n}) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(g(x^{2^{k-1}}) - g(x^{2^k})\right)$ and for $|x| < 1$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^{2^n} = 0 \implies \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g(x^{2^n}) = g(0) = 0$. For integrals on RHS, they can be expressed in terms of  Beta function.

Oh thank you so much for your hint, I guess it is actually solvable in some ways but I'm not educated enough to find the final answer

The $\sqrt{1+x^2} + {}$ doesn't belong before the infinite sum. The $n=1$ term is the $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ term.

This seems really challenging for a Calc I book. Were there any hints, is it marked (**) or something, are you sure you copied it exactly?

Yeah I have edit them, just a mistake. Also, I know it is too difficult for Calc I, which is why I firstly dont think it can be solved but in fact it is

@achillehui. What would it be for  $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2} + x^2f(x^3)$ ?

@ClaudeLeibovici In that case, $f(x) = \frac1x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^{3^n}\sqrt{1-x^{2\cdot 3^n}}$ so $$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \int_{-1}^1 x^{3^n-1} \sqrt{1-x^{2\cdot 3^n-1}} dx = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n}\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-y^2}dy = \frac{3\pi}{4}$$ the answer given in the book.

@achillehui. Thanks !

Answer (assume the original problem posted by OP is correct):
$$I=\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{-(2n-3)!!}{((2n+2)2^{m}-1)n!2^{n-1}}=2.42\ldots \tag{1}$$
Given that $f\in C([-1,1])$, By Stone-Weierstrass theorem, we can approximate $f(x)$ by  polynomials: $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{2k}$. Note that $f(x)$ is even and we must approximate $f(x)$ by a sequence $P_n(x)$ that tends to be an infinite series, otherwise $P_n(x)-x^{2}P_n(x^2)$ (a finite series) will never get near to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (an infinite series).
Now we use the expansion $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u_kx^{2k}$.
Put everything in: $f(x)-x^{2}f(x^2)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. By balancing coefficients:
\begin{cases}
a_{k}=u_k\ ,&k\ \operatorname{even} \\
a_{k}=a_{\frac{k-1}{2}}+u_k\ , &k\ \operatorname{odd}
\end{cases}
Solve the sequence $a_k$ (in terms of $u_k$) and put in $I=\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2a_{k}}{2k+1}$ to obtain:
$$I=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2u_k\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2((k+1)2^{m}-1)+1} \tag{2}$$
Now use the fact that $u_k=\frac{-(2k-3)!!}{k!2^k}$, we arrived at $(1)$
Comment I believe the problem was misprinted. It should have been:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}+x^{2}f(x^3)$$
However, I think it's still solvable. I didn't perform detailed solution because I just want to show how we should solve it "even when the problem is misprinted".
This desmos graph confirms my calculations.

Dang cap a oi mac du e ko hieu j het, e chi xem co giai dc ko thoi chu e dung phuong phap sua de r

Stone Wierstrass does not imply that you can write a continuous function as the sum of a power series. Yes, there exists a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ converging uniformly to $f$, but they are not necessarily  such that $P_{n+1}-P_n$ is proportional to $x^{n+1}.$

@LetacGérard I see. I didn't make my point clear. Such sequence $P_n$ (as pointed out existed) must be an infinite series, otherwise $P_{n}(x)-x^{2}P_{n}(x^2)$ (a finite series) will never approximate $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (an infinite series). Fixed it.

If you do what @achille hui suggested in comments
$$f(x) = \frac1{x^2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{2^n} \sqrt{1-x^{2^n}}$$ for $n>1$
$$I_n=\int_{-1}^{+1}\frac {x^{2^n} \sqrt{1-x^{2^n}} }{x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2^n}\frac {\Gamma \left(\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\right) } {\Gamma \left(\frac{5\times 2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n}}\right) }$$ and, for any $n \geq 2$
$$\frac 2 5 <\frac{I_{n+1}}{I_n}<\frac 12$$ Then, a fast convergence for
$$\int_{-1}^{+1}f(x)\,dx)=\frac \pi 2+ \sqrt \pi\,\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {\Gamma \left(\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\right) } {2^n\,\Gamma \left(\frac{5\times 2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n}}\right) }$$
I did not find the expression for the summation but the result is $2.4236836$ which is not $\frac {3\pi}4$ even if it is close to.
Edit
Consider
$$A_n=\frac {\sqrt \pi \,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\right) } {2^n\,\Gamma \left(\frac{5\times 2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n}}\right) }$$ and let $a=2^{-n}$
$$A_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } a \Gamma (1-a)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{5}{2}-a\right)}$$ Expandind for small $a$
$$A_n=\frac 43\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k\,a^k$$ where the first coefficients are (with $L=2\log(2)$)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & \frac{8}{3}-L \\
 3 & \left(\frac{52}{9}-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}\right)-\frac{8L}{3}+\frac{L^2}{2}\\
 4 &\left(-2 \zeta (3)+\frac{320}{27}-\frac{4 \pi
   ^2}{9}\right)+\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}
-\frac{52}{9}\right) L+\frac{4L^2}{3}-\frac{L^3}{6}\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Back to $n$ and summing
$$\int_{-1}^{+1}f(x)\,dx =\frac \pi 2+\frac 43\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha_k }{2^k \left(2^k-1\right) }$$
Using the terms given above, this leads to $2.42104$.
Edit
As a function of the number of terms $n$ used in the summation, converted to decimals, the results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \int_{-1}^{+1}f(x)\,dx -\frac \pi 2\\
 1 & 0.66666667 \\
 2 & 0.80893026 \\
 3 & 0.84219132 \\
 4 & 0.85024850 \\
 5 & 0.85223193 \\
 6 & 0.85272400 \\
 7 & 0.85284654 \\
 8 & 0.85287712 \\
 9 & 0.85288475 \\
 10 & 0.85288666 \\
 11 & 0.85288714 \\
 12 & 0.85288726 \\
 13 & 0.85288729 \\
 14 & 0.85288729 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ which has nothing to do with $\frac \pi 4$.

I think it is unsolvable or at least, lack of condition to make it solvable. Here my proof:
Start with what we easily have $$2\int_{0}^1f(x)dx= {\pi\over2}+\int_{0}^1\sqrt{x}f(x)dx(1)$$
And
$$\int_{0}^1xf(x)dx = 2/3$$
Let $$\int_{0}^1\sqrt{x}f(x)dx=k$$ We have:$$\int_{0}^1(2\sqrt{x}f(x)-xf(x))dx =\int_{0}^1(2-\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x}f(x)dx=2k-{2\over3}$$
Also from (1) we have:  $$\int_{0}^12(2-\sqrt{x})f(x)dx = \pi$$
$$\Rightarrow\int_{0}^1(2-\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^12(2-\sqrt{x})f(x)dx = \int_{0}^1(4-x)f(x)dx = \pi + 2k - {2\over3}$$
which is, however, the same as (1)
Therefore, as $k$ and $f(x)$ are undetermined, the answer depends on $k$, so it is unsolvable no matter which techniques (that I can think of) are used if there is no other conditions contained

This does not prove that the problem is unsolvable. It could be the case that for any function satisfying the functional equation, the value of $k$ is always the same.

Yeah but  I dont think I can  easily find that function

Um yeah you right, it is actually solvable and there may be a way to solve this, I just wrongly assume.

Could we have the reference of the calculus textbook? Can you consider the possibility of a misprint, like $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}+xf(x^2)?$

@LetacGérard https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qt8OM_zhHfoGhqv9TnvlVPNtZXagCliP/view?usp=sharing, it is actually curriculum document of our professor, you can check this problem on page 53, exercise 3. In case of misprint, the result would be different from the problem's answer. But I just try hard to see if it is solvable or not, because I know putting too much efforts on it would be such waste of time

@aye123456 Are you sure it's on page 53? I couldn't find it.

@QuýNhân page 53 on the document and page 57 on drive

@LetacGérard If $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2} + x f(x^2)$, then $\int_{-1}^1 f(x), dx = \pi$. But as Quý Nhân noted, if $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2} + x^2 f(x^3)$, then $\int_{-1}^1 f(x), dx = \frac 34 \pi$, matching the book's answer. But yes, both versions are much easier than this likely misprint.

aschepler, your answer is the reasonable one,
